# Not able to map the data

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have one scenario which I am unable to achieve.

Scenario-

I am having Leads entity in which I have n no of leads.  In the leads form I have some fields and one sub grid I have added.

Sub-grid is of the form -

Stakeholder name                   Role of Stakeholder

x                                                  Manager

y                                                    Budget owner

.

.

.

Now what is happening in sub-grid we are displaying views and whatever we are adding in the views everything will be displayed there in that sub-grid.

Now my requirement is that I wanted to display only the stakeholders and roles of stakeholder  which are related to that particular lead not all the data which are there in views and same with other leads in the lead entity.

I have used sub-grid so that I can achieve that multi-column and multi-row way.

So please can anyone help with this problem like how to achieve this thing?.

Note - I just want to achieve "I wanted to display only the stakeholders and roles of stakeholder  which are related to that particular lead not all the data which are there in views and same with other leads in the lead entity" That's it. If we can achieve this without using sub-grid then also its fine its just that we should we able to add multiple columns with multiple values.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use below settings in your stakeholder subgrid and it shall work.

[image]

[image]